# How to push text baseline to the bottom of the parent block?

Tags: html, css

There is some layout:

```css
.block {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
.contents {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.contens > * {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.content1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
}
.content2 {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="contents">
    <span class="content1"></span>
    <span class="content2">Foo</span>
    <span class="content3">Bar</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to make text baseline of `.contents` be pushed to the bottom of the `.block` regardless of the font face?

Expected result:

[image: Expected result]

Shifting down the `.contents` block by `bottom: -0.1em;` is not suitable because font faces have different baseline level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed **line-height** to 0, added **overflow:hidden**

```css
.block {
  background: #aaa;
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.contents {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 10px;
  line-height:0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.contents > * {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
.content1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #000;
}
.content2 {
  font-size: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="contents">
    <span class="content1"></span>
    <span class="content2">Foo</span>
    <span class="content3">Bar</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to add a usage note: there MUST be any inline-block element in `.contents` for this method to work.

Answer (score 1):

Just set css `line-height: 0;`

See : http://codepen.io/ivoglent/pen/KzaWNG